# silverlight5 nUnit test class INotifyDataErrorInfo defined assembly not found

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, telerik, nunit

Our application using silverlight 5 with MVVM design pattern and Telerik UI for silverlight.
We try to right unit test for our View Models that are using INotifyDataErrorInfo interface. But it raise Error,

```
The type 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyDataErrorInfo' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
```

I implemented the INotify interface in our test class,

```
[TestFixture]
public class ViewModelTest : LabOra.Applications.View.ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    [Test]
    public void ContactVmTest()
    {
        var vm = new ContactsVM();
        // Console.WriteLine(vm.NumberOfRecords);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

But still the same Error. What is the wrong ?

Comment: What is your test project template (Silverlight application/ Microsoft Unit Test project)?

Comment: @RAJ , I'm using nUnit, First add Class library to solution and then add nUnit from NuGet to that class library.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use normal class library project to test silverlight ViewModels their runtime are different. Sometime you can succede but if you have any custom silverlight project reference it wont work. You need silverlight application or class library project to test silverlight viewmodels.

1. Check your Test Project Template, Because you want to test Silverlight class library as your view models are in Silverlight library project, You need Silverlight class library application as your test project.
2. Download Latest version of Silverlight toolkit. Within that toolkit you should have below dlls under path.

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Toolkit\dec11\Testing
3. Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing.dll
4. Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTesting.Silverlight.dll

Add these two references to your silverlight project.

Modify App.xaml.cs of the silverlight project (You are going to use for the test) as below

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RootVisual = UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage();

    }
```

Set the project as start up project and run.

Comment: For better handling of automated tests (such as part of a build process) you can use Statlight, which creates an in-memory browser for testing, rather than the microsoft testing framework which requires you to actually run your application in a browser. The only downside is that your tests won't show up in the VS test runner, but if you use ReSharper you can make use agUnit which *does* allow you to run your tests through a test explorer.

Comment: Agree with Mashton, Even I am using Resharper and there is visual studio plugin for AgUnit once you install AgUnit you can use Resharper test runner to run all silverlight unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

after googling plenty of times/days without any proper solution to my scenario. i found [this site](http://blog.house-of-code.com/unit-testing-in-silverlight/), he explains it in different different ways. MS Unit, NUnit all the stuff with silverlight 5 unit testing.

To do unit testing on silverlight 5, MVVM app I used [Silverlight Toolkit for silverlight 5](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). After installing it, in Visual studio 2012 you will not have silverlight test template as some examples on internet as describe even after installing silverlight toolkit. I just create another silverlight 5 project into my existing project solution and create class and put Annotations. To do this you need to add unit testing reference to your newly created project.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void load()
    {
         Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }

}
```

Those are in, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Toolkit\dec11\Testing` folder,browse and add.

change your test project App.xaml.cs startup event,

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RootVisual = UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage();
    }
```

Finally, in your original project (ProjectName.web), set it as start up project, if you didn't and set start page as your testing project page.([This link will help you](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/78540/Unit-Testing-a-Silverlight-View-Model-Style-Modal))

Also Thank you RAJ, for your guidance.